# Numerically solve system of 64 equations with 64 variables in matrix form

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I have 2 matrix $A$ and $B$ both of size 16x16. Most of the values $A_{i,j}$ and $B_{i,j}$ for the same couple $(i,j)$ are equal to 0. The remaining ones are a positive floating number for $A$ and a non-linear combination of the 64 variables for $B$.

In other words, for any $(i,j)$, $A_{i,j} = B_{i,j} = 0$ OR $A_{i,j} = number$ and $B_{i,j} =$ $non-linear$ $combination$ $of$ $the$ $64$ $variables$.

In the end, I have a 64 equations with 64 variables equations system in the form $A = B$.

I am trying to solve this with `NSolve` on a workstation with 128 Gb of RAM. After 72 hours of computation at nearly 120 Gb of RAM non-stop... I'm starting to wonder if it will ever converge...

I just read that another function may be performing better `FindRoot`. I do have an idea of the value for each of the 64 variables, however, I do not know how I can input those starting points for the 64 variables.

**4x4 example:**

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}50 & 3 & 10 & 2\\\ 3 & 60 & 7 & 1\\\ 10 & 7 & 55 & 4\\\ 2 & 1 & 4 & 45 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$B = \begin{pmatrix}b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13} & 0\\\ b_{21} & b_{22} & 0 & 0\\\ b_{31} & 0 & b_{33} & b_{34}\\\ 0 & 0 & b_{43} & b_{44} \end{pmatrix}$$

```
A = {{50, 3, 10, 2}, {3, 60, 7, 1}, {10, 7, 55, 4}, {2, 1, 4, 45}}
B = {{Subscript[b, 11], Subscript[b, 12], Subscript[b, 13], 
  0}, {Subscript[b, 12], Subscript[b, 22], 0, 0}, {Subscript[b, 13], 
  0, Subscript[b, 33], Subscript[b, 34]}, {0, 0, Subscript[b, 34], 
  Subscript[b, 44]}}
```

Solve $A = B^{-1}$.

```
Binv = Inverse[B]
NSolve[Table[
   If[MatchQ[B[[i, j]], Subscript[b, x_]], Binv[[i, j]], 0], {i, 
    4}, {j, 4}] == 
  Table[If[MatchQ[B[[i, j]], Subscript[b, x_]], A[[i, j]], 0], {i, 
    4}, {j, 4}]]
```

Solution:

$$B=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}\frac{27497}{1321025} & -\frac{1}{997} & -\frac{1}{265} & 0 \\-\frac{1}{997} & \frac{50}{2991} & 0 & 0 \\-\frac{1}{265} & 0 & \frac{136093}{7167985} & -\frac{4}{2459} \\0 & 0 & -\frac{4}{2459} & \frac{55}{2459} \\\end{array}\right)$$

I would like to find the same solution with `FindRoot` by using the values $A^{-1}_{i,j}$ as starting point for $b_{i,j}$ but I don't know how to provide this input to `FindRoot`.

Additionnaly, are there also any other parameters I should provide to `FindRoot`?

Comment: Impossible to say without the any detailed code.

Comment: The solution to $A = B^{-1}$ seems to be $B=A^{-1}$, no?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ok, it seems I poorly explained the problem in this post. Sorry. $A$ is a matrix where there are no $0$ at the beginning. But, before the solving, I replace the values $A_{i,j}$ with $0$ IF $B_{i,j} = 0$. Then, $B^{-1}$ elements are all a non linear combination of the $b_{i,j}$, the unkowns that I am looking for. So the solving as too solve element-wise the problem to figure out what the $b_{i,j}$ are. In other words, if I put $0$ in $A$ where $B_{i,j}=0$, and then invert $A$, I won't get a $0$ anymore in the location $A^{-1}_{i,j}$ where $B_{i,j}=0$.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I added the matrix definition, but all the code is here. I am simply defining $A$ and $B$, then I invert $B$ which gives a matrix of equations, and finally, I create 2 tables from $A$ and $Binv$ where a $0$ is placed at the location $(i, j)$ if $B_{i,j} = 0$. Then I solve the equality between those tables. As `NSolve` is not converging, I would like to use `FindRoot` where I define the starting point for the variable $b_{i,j}$ as $A^{-1}_{i,j}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in your toy model, using the respective entries of the inverse of `A` for initializing `FindRoot` seems to work quite fine:

```
B0 = B /. Subscript[b, _] :> 1;
eq = DeleteCases[Flatten[B0 Det[B] UpperTriangularize[Inverse[B] - A]], 0];
Binit = DeleteCases[Flatten[UpperTriangularize[B0 Inverse[A]]], 0];
vars = DeleteCases[Flatten[UpperTriangularize[B]], 0];
FindRoot[Thread[eq == 0], Transpose[{vars, Binit}]]
```

> {Subscript[b, 11] -> 0.0208149, Subscript[b, 12] -> -0.00100301, 
>    Subscript[b, 13] -> -0.00377358, Subscript[b, 22] -> 0.0167168, 
>    Subscript[b, 33] -> 0.0189862, Subscript[b, 34] -> -0.00162668, 
>    Subscript[b, 44] -> 0.0223668}

I remove the redundant equations with `UpperTriangularize` and `DeleteCases` because otherwise  `FindRoot` would complain about the fact that there are more equations than variables.

I also multiply the equations with `Det[B]`; this way the equations become polynomial -- beforehand they were rational. Rational equations can be problematic for Newton's method (which is employed by `FindRoot`) because it can lead to division by zero. In this case, it doesn't make a difference, though.

Comment: Thanks :) As I am new to Mathematica, could you detail a bit what the code does? Are you also deleting the values below the diagonal? (which is actually great because those equations are redundant).

Comment: What is the asset of transforming the equations into polynomial instead of the rational?

Comment: One more question :) Why is the fraction obtained from the inversion $eq / det(B)$? Is this due to the form of the matrix $B$? Will it always be the case no matter where I have $B_{i,j} = 0$ as long as $B$ is symmetric and $B_{i,i} /neq 0$. i.e. will it always be the $det(B)$ if I have symmetric $B$ with a filled diagonal and some $0$ on the off-diagonal elements?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule

Comment: Thanks for all the explanation. While going full scale I ran into a problem. The computation of the determinant of $B$ (16x16) is taking forever. Is this step really needed since you say that it doesn't make a difference in this case? I added the 16x16 matrix in this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/204374/determinant-of-16x16-symbolic-matrix

Comment: As I said, the determinant is not absolutely necessary. However, in some form or the other, the determinant will probably show up anyways when you compute the inverse of `B`. That's due to Cramer's rule. This is why any ansatz with inverses of symbolic matrices has to fail utterly if only the size of the matrix is large enough. So if also the inversion of `B` takes 12 h to compute, this tells me that you are on the wrong track to whatever you really want to accomplish...

Comment: The inversion takes only 5 minutes.. that's why I think it is weird that the determinant takes so long.

Comment: Then why do you ask me if it works or not? After `FindRoot` has terminated, you can test for your self whether the result is correct or not.

Comment: Indeed, but I am not at this step yet. The weird part is that the inverse of B works fine (5 minutes computation), but computing its determinant takes forever... In your solution, you multiply $B0$ with $Det[B]$ and with $Binv - A$. Since the determinant took forever, I'll try it by taking it out..